# Reading local xhtml files with xht extension with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, file-extension

We have some **local** xhtml files to create their thumbnails. But for some reason, their extensions are xht instead of xhtml. When converting these files with phantomjs it couldnt do it, but when try with xhtml extension it does it correctly. How can we tell phantomjs treat them as xhtml?

```
var system = require('system');

function changeExtension(path, newExt) {
    var lastInd = path.lastIndexOf("."),
        newPath = path;
    if( lastInd>0 ) {
        newPath = path.substring(0,lastInd+1)+newExt;
    }
    else {
        newPath = path+"."+newExt;
    }
    return newPath;
}

function createThumb(page, next) {
    var path = system.args[next];
    if( path.indexOf("file://")===-1 ) {
        path = "file://" + (path.charAt(0)==='/' ? '' : '/') + path;
    }
    page.open(path, function(request, response) {
        var newPath = changeExtension(path, "jpeg").substr("file:///".length);
        page.render(newPath, {format: "jpeg", quality: 25});
        if( next+1<system.args.length ) {
            createThumb(page, next+1);
        }
        else {
            phantom.exit();
        }
    }); 
}

if( system.args.length>1 ) {
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    createThumb(page, 1);   
}
```

Comment: it is strange that problem is the file protocol at the begining of local url. But why it does not make any problem for xhtml extension but for xht?

Comment: I looked into the source code. XHTML is parsed differently from everything else. I haven't found out if this is based on the file extension, but this is possible.